# Java Game of Life not checking neighbors correctly

Tags: java, conways-game-of-life

I set an initial pattern of cells ([initial state screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAf5v.png)) for my game of life to evolve, but the code does not seem to evolve the cells correctly. Instead, it stops [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3trP.png), but this generation should not look like this. (I apologize for the inconvenience, but I cannot post what the state should look like due to lack of reputation).  I've looked through my evolution method, but I can't seem to find the problem since I believe all of the surrounding cells are accounted for. Help is much appreciated.

```
public void setCellAlive (int row, int col){
if (row <= numberRows){
          colony [row][col] = 1;
    }else{
    System.out.println ("Index out of range.");
    }
}
public void setCellDead (int row, int col){
    if (row <= numberRows){
        colony [row][col]=0;
    }else{
         System.out.println ("Index out of range.");
    }
}
private void evolution(int i, int j) {
    int left = 0, right = 0, up = 0, down = 0;
    int topLeft = 0, topRight = 0, bottomLeft = 0, bottomRight = 0;

    if (j < colony.length - 1) {
        right = colony[i][j + 1];
        if(i>0)
            bottomRight = colony[i - 1][j + 1];
        if (i < colony.length - 1)
            topRight = colony[i + 1][j + 1];
    }

    if (j > 0) {
        left = colony[i][j - 1];
        if (i > 0)
            bottomLeft = colony[i - 1][j - 1];
        if (i< colony.length-1)
            topLeft = colony[i + 1][j - 1];
    }

    if (i > 0)
        up = colony[i + 1][j];
    if (i < colony.length - 1)
        down = colony[i - 1][j];

    int sum = left + right + up + down + topLeft + topRight
            + bottomLeft + bottomRight;

    if (colony[i][j] == 1) {
        if (sum < 2)
            setCellDead (i,j);
        if (sum > 3)
            setCellDead(i,j);
    }

    else {
        if (sum == 3)
            setCellAlive (i,j);
    }

}
public void updateColony() {
    for (int i = 0; i < colony.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < colony[i].length; j++) {
            evolution(i, j);
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: well, you could create a bigger image containing both states and use it instead :-)

Comment: @Leo I could edit that now, if it helps.

Comment: It's hard to tell since we can't see the code that calls `evolution`.  But my guess is that when you set a cell to Alive or Dead, it affects the computation of the rest of the _same_ generation, and that's not supposed to happen.

Comment: @ajb Yeah, that's what I thought-I'm 90% sure that the evolve is birthing and killing cells in the same generation, but I'm not sure how to fix that. I've added the method that calls evolution at the bottom of the original code snippet.

Comment: You'll probably need to have two copies of the array while you're creating the generation.  (Be careful when copying a 2-D array.  A 2-D array is an array of references to 1-D arrays, and if you just copy the references instead of the data, you will run into trouble.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are changing the values of the array as you go and then using the new (rather than old) values to decide the state of further cells. The solution is to create a new array each tick and then set its values using the old array:

```
public void updateColony() {
    int [][] nextStep = new int[colony.length][colony[0].length];
    for (int i = 0; i < colony.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < colony[i].length; j++) {
            evolution(nextStep, i, j);
        }
    }
    colony = nextStep;
}
```

Comment: @pianos: This is the general idea.  Note also that `evolution` will need to read from `colony` and write into `nextStep`.  Most important: In `sprinter`'s code, `nextStep` starts out with all "dead" cells, so you won't need `setCellDead` any more, and you will have to make sure cells that are already alive and need to stay alive are set with `setCellAlive`.